# List vector with all the occurences from another dataframe

Tags: r, vector

I am trying to do something like:
I have this dataframe

```
Name   Distance  
James  2
James  1
Maria  5
Thomas 2
Thomas 1
James  4
```

I also have the dataframe that contais all the names, if it helps.

And retrieve 3 separate dataframes that should look like this:

```
   James  2 1 4
   Thomas 2 1
   Maria  5
```

Notice that I don't want to sum it, just get the values and I the list is much longer of names, so doing one by one is not optimal.

Comment: Are you referring to the conversion of a data frame from a long format to a wide format?

Comment: *"And retrieve 3 separate dataframes"* So the output should be three *separate* `data.frame`s with one row each? I'm confused because your expected output looks like a single `data.frame`.

Comment: `split(df$Distance,df$Name)` does not return a data.frame but does seem to make sense here. Does that help?

Comment: Or perhaps something like this `aggregate(Distance ~ Name, df, paste0, collapse = " ")`?

Comment: I want diferent data.frames since they will have diferent dimensions... @MauritsEvers It is almost what I want, but the results are all in a place, and I need to further treat them

Comment: @Florian split could be a solution, can you please elaborate how can I use it and save the diferent data frames with diferent names ?

Comment: @DTYK cant understand your question

Comment: @L8call I have added my suggestion as an answer, since it might be a bit too long for the comments.

Comment: @RonakShah it is not the samething as I dont have a timevar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to not store the results in a `data.frame` but in a list, since the results will have different dimensions. You can obtain the desired list with

```
my_list = split(df$Distance,df$Name)
```

which returns:

```
$`James`
[1] 2 1 4

$Maria
[1] 5

$Thomas
[1] 2 1
```

Then for example, you can get the result for a single person as

```
my_list[['James']]
> 2 1 4
```

or get the sum for each person with

```
lapply(my_list,sum)
```

which returns:

```
$`James`
[1] 7

$Maria
[1] 5

$Thomas
[1] 3
```

Hope this helps!